# Fastest weighted probability table design in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-performance

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
Id (int), Input (string), Output (string)
```

Given some input X, I need to be able to get a random output Y but weighted according to the frequency that X-Y occurs in the table.

Here are some sample rows:

```
 1. In1, Out1
 2. In1, Out2
 3. In1, Out2
 4. In2, Out3
 5. In2, Out4
```

So in this case, for 'In1' my possible randomly generated outputs are either Out1 or Out2. It would be twice as likely to generate 'Out2' since the In1-Out2 transition occurs twice in the database as opposed to In1-Out1 which only appears once. For In2 either Out3 or Out4 will be generated with an equal probability.

Which of the following would be more performant? (or is there a third approach that I'm overlooking)

1. Duplicating rows where the Input and Output values are identical

Then we just make a single SQL call: (depending on mysql or mssql)

```
select * from table where Input = X order by rand() limit 1;
select top 1 * from table where Input = X order by NEWID();
```

2. Storing the frequency of Input X to Input Y in the table

So now the table has an additional column: Frequency

The previous table would instead look like this:

```
 1. In1, Out1, 1
 2. In1, Out2, 2
 3. In2, Out3, 1
 4. In2, Out4, 1
```

My table will be a lot smaller but it seems like whenever I want to get a weighted random row for some input value X, I'll need to first fetch all rows where Input = X into memory and then do the probability test in code.

I'm going to be making this weighted fetch thousands of time per second, so speed is of the utmost importance. The table is likely going to contain greater than a million records.

The program is written C# and it'll be using either SQL Server or MySQL as the backend, not sure if that's going to make much of a difference.

Comment: How large will the clusters of inputs get? How much duplication is expected?

Comment: I'd say your first option is going to perform better, as your second option will require two reads of the table - one to get the sum to do the weighting, and another to get the record. It really comes down to what your "millions of records" look like - number of unique inputs, number of unique outputs, number of, and quantity of duplicates. Additionally, whilst it looks like you will need to do a lot of reading, what does write performance need to look like? how frequently will this dataset be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A third (likely the fastest approach) would be to take a variant of the second approach, but using a decimal number range like so:

1. In1, Out1, 0, 0.33
2. In1, Out2, 0.33, 1
3. In2, Out3, 0, 0.5
4. In2, Out4, 0.5, 1

To "pick" one weighted, choose any input plus a random number between 0 and 1 (exclusive) and in your SQL query check this random number for >= min and < max. That can be optimized perfectly and takes into account the weight.

You can make sure that the numbers are correctly distributed on insert by using a trigger.

Comment: Neat solution. Falls down if write performance is important. Also, you need to keep a tally of each "in-out" pair, if you want to be able to update the weight "range". adding 1 extra In1-Out2 pair will change differently if there are currently 33 In1-Out1 and 77 in1-out2 vs 330000 in1-out1 and 770000 in1-out2 pairs...

Comment: @AndrewP Since the OP asked about good query performance I designed it that way; if write performance was important one could also keep his second approach and compute the ranges dynamically with a window function quite easily. I'd expect this to perform quite good as well...

Comment: thus, neat solution :) Still need to track the tally though

Comment: @AndrewP Sure, but that could be tracked independently in a separate smaller table that has a integer count for each (distinct) Input. Any maybe this is not an issue at all if the data is computed based on another data set and adding items after initialization is not required? Only the OP knows the answer... ;)